# How to obtain test cases

Tags: testing, static-analysis, soot

Recently I focused on the static analysis software, especially the [Indus](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) and and [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) Java frameworks. I want to test these software. Can anyone can provide comprehensive test cases? I think the test cases I write are not typical enough.

Comment: There are a lot of types of tests: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing

Answer (score 1):

My standard advice in evaluating static analysis tools is to test them on the real software you’ll be using them for:  *“Pitfall II:* Don’t buy a tool based on bugs it finds in other people’s code.  Before you commit to a static analysis tool, make sure that it finds important bugs in your real code. Bugs found in open source or demo code can be very impressive; but your organization’s code, while it’s under development (which is the cheapest time to find bugs) will be very different from code which has already been made public.”  *Supplemental Proceedings of the 21st IEEE International Symposium on Software Reliability Engineering,* http://pobox.com/~flash/Static_Analysis_Deployment_Pitfalls.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to contact the vendors of these software packages and ask them for test cases. It is in their own interest to have as many as possible right now.

Answer (score -1):

One way of obtaining test cases is holding onto the input files you get from your users when things break -- maybe distill the input to the least amount of input necessary to trigger the bug in the broken version, and make sure newer versions work correctly.

Comment: @Fiary, in what way could I improve my answer to make it useful to you?